# compiling php4 headers instead of php5

Tags: php, php4, php-extension

I'm compiling certain extensions for PHP on dreamhost PS server.
I got an error and found that it happens when php4 headers are used instead of php5 headers.

running phpinfo shows the server runs php5. however php-v on the command line gives php4.

How can I make the compilation use php5 instead of php4 on my server? Is there an environment variable of some kind and if so how can I change it (new to linux)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find out where on the box PHP 5 is installed. You might try `locate phpize` on your shell. The same directory should contain a `php-config` executable. The path might be found in the phpinfo() output. Check there for the Configuraiton cammand and in there for the --prefix parameter.

If there are multiple PHP isntallations incl. phpize you can compile extensions using da selected version by using the correct paths:

```
$ cd extension_source
$ /full/path/to/bin/phpize
$ ./configure --with-php-config=/full/path/to/bin/php-config
$ make
$ make install
```